# Python get package metadata from source distribution on pypiserver?

Tags: python

How can a read package metadata from a `tar.gz` file that I pull down from local pypi server?

On my local machine I can use [`pkginfo`](https://pythonhosted.org/pkginfo/distributions.html#introspecting-source-distributions) and run `mypackage = SDist('docs/examples/mypackage-0.1.tar.gz')`

Which will give me the metadata.

However, I am having trouble reading from a file stream using requests?

I have tried

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.tar.gz') as fp:
    fp.write(r.content)
    fp.seek(0)
    gzf = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=fp)
    print(gzf.name)
    pgkfoo = SDist(filename=gzf.name)
```

The print statments outputs `C:\Users\my_user_acct\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpz2v7vcen.tar.gz`

However, I keep getting a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\my_user_acct\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\tmpz2v7vcen.tar.gz'`, I checked and I am able to read/write files in that directory.

also `r.url='http://localhost:8080/packages/model_bar-0.1.tar.gz#md5=e6da10bef8626a4e3dcf358fe4787a8c'`

Comment: You are trying to open an already opened file, Windows can be a little touchy about those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [yorodm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393308/yorodm)

I was able to get this to work, also didn't need to use gzip.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.tar.gz', delete=False) as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    f.seek(0)
    file_ = f.name
pkg_info = SDist(file_)
os.remove(file_)
```